# Generator and filter with context managers

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

Let's consider this code sample:

```
class Foobar():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __enter__(self):
        print("inside enter", self)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("inside exit", self)
        # Save self.data to disk

    def get(self):
        return self.x

    def set(self, data):
        # Set some data, that is then written in __exit__
        self.data = data


def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        with Foobar(i) as f:
            yield f
```

The basic concept is to have a class with context managers and a generator that produces such objects. The normal case would be to call it like this:

```
for x in gen():
    # Manipulate the Object
    x.set("foobar")
```

While in this case, every object is written, now we apply a filter first:

```
for x in filter(lambda x: x.get() % 2 == 0, gen()):
    x.set("foobar")
```

The problem is now, that the manipulated object is not written to disk, because the `__exit__` function is actually called in the filter function.

Is it possible to have working context managers in a loop plus the filtering?

Of course, one could write another `gen()` function, that only yields certain Objects but using `filter()` on the object is much more convenient.
Yet another method would be to filter in the loop, e.g.

```
for x in gen():
    if x.get() % 2 == 0:
        x.set("foobar")
```

Comment: work fine for me, are you using python 2?? if so use instead itertools.ifilter

Comment: @Copperfield okay, well thats interessting! Yes I used `python`, which aliases to `pyton2.7` on my machine. Using `python3`, it works as expected! I did not expected to have a difference between python2 and 3 to be honest. Thanks for pointing that out. And yes, itertools.ifilter behaves the same was as python3 natively.

Comment: as you should know, there are several differences between py2 and py3, among them is that filter, map, zip, range act like generators in py3, while in py2 they produce the whole resulting list at once, which the cause of your problem here...

Comment: Oh, another alternative is using a generator expression to do the filtering: `for x in ( y for y in gen() if y.get()%2==0): ...`